# How to use Xpath for the given XML

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy, soapui

XML file is

```
<Makes>
    <e>
        <Code>a</Code>
        <Name>b</Name>
    </e>
</Makes>
```

I want to fetch the Code.

Comment: What have you tried? There are a few valid xpath expressions that will get you the `<Code>` element, or its content.

Comment: I tried with //Makes/Code. It is working if i don't have <e> tag, but it is not working with <e> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *that* XML, `/Makes/e/Code` should work (as would `//Makes/e/Code[0]`). If you wanted all `Code` elements, in any arbitrary document, then you *could* use `//Code`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
/Makes/e/Code/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
1) /Makes/e/Code
2) /Makes//Code
3) //Code
```